# Store audio video from rtsp stream with steamping at every n min

Tags: gstreamer

Actually i am not able to store all three task in one file.
1-spleting  file
2-steamping
3-storing both audio video in single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try various methods

gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://admin:password#@192.168.1.109:80 name= u u. ! audioconvert ! m. u. ! videoconvert ! m.  avimux name=m ! multifilesink location=test2%d.wav next-file=4 max-file-size=5120000000

gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://admin:password#@192.168.1.109:80 name= u u. ! audioconvert ! m. u. ! videoconvert ! avenc_mpeg2video ! m.  matroskamux name=m ! filesink location=ts.mp4

gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://admin:password#@192.168.1.109:80 name= u u. ! audioconvert ! m. u. ! videoconvert ! m.  avimux name=m ! multifilesink location=test.mkv

gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://admin:password#@192.168.1.109:80 name= u u. ! audioconvert ! m. u. ! videoconvert ! m.  matroskamux name=m ! filesink location=test.mkv

gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://admin:password#@192.168.1.109:80 ! audioconvert ! m.   uridecodebin uri=rtsp://admin:password#@192.168.1.109:80 ! videoconvert ! m.  matroskamux name=m ! filesink location=test.mkv

but this one do all task at once

gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://admin:password#@192.168.1.109:80 name= u u. ! audioconvert ! m. u. ! videoconvert ! avenc_mpeg2video ! textoverlay text="Utsav" valignment=top halignment=left font-desc="Sans, 72" ! m.  matroskamux name=m  ! multifilesink location=success2%d.mp4 next-file=4 max-file-size=10240000